# How to customize an actionSheet for social sharing to get one like as if i did with an activityViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiactionsheet, ios5.1

I'm working with iOS 5.1. I'm using Action Sheet to do the social sharing functionality.

Is there a method to customize it to get something like in ios 6 like in this photo's [link](http://www.absoluteripple.com/uploads/4/8/5/4/4854975/8948484.png?129)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at ShareThis. It has already done a lot of the work for you. https://github.com/ign/ShareThis

For iOS 5 compatibility, try REActivityViewController.
https://github.com/romaonthego/REActivityViewController

Comment: thank you :) there is too much code than i thought , i'll try to understand this solution and i'll see if it works on my project

Comment: i'm using now this example https://github.com/relikd/OGActionChooser but i can not make buttons of the chooser do the share, can u help me plz ?